# Incorrect TenantID Being Passed to Azure Causing Access Denied

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I am trying to build an ASP.Net application that is hosted on Azure.

I am receiving an error when launching the application in Debug mode from Visual Studio. See below:

[image]

My app is failing right off the bat as you can see. I saw somewhere that the Tenant ID f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a is a special tenant that is rejected by the key vault. However, that is not my tenant ID. When I look in Azure Active Directory Overview, I see a different TenantID than the one being called out in the error.

I found my TenantID in one of my solution files, secrets1.arm.json as shown below:

[image]

And the contents of that file are:

[image]

I have enable all access policies for my app, and for me.
[image]

I have been googling and looking at what could be causing this issue, but I don't know what else to try. I am obviously new. I am a winforms developer who is trying to learn ASP and Azure.

Thank you.

Edits:

Here is the full error message:

An unhandled exception of type 'Azure.RequestFailedException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Service request failed.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)

Content:
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Access denied to first party service.\r\nCaller: name=from-infra;tid=f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a;appid=872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-xxxxxxxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/\r\nVault: ShoppingCartvault;location=northcentralus","innererror":{"code":"AccessDenied"}}}

Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
x-ms-keyvault-region: northcentralus
x-ms-client-request-id: d24931b2-77f4-4a3e-9603-15bbf23f558c
x-ms-request-id: e82c726a-1c54-423f-b0cc-5b217b3b2e0a
x-ms-keyvault-service-version: 1.9.48.0
x-ms-keyvault-network-info: conn_type=Ipv4;addr=xx.xxx.46.72;act_addr_fam=InterNetwork;
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2021 20:46:15 GMT
Content-Length: 346
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1

And here is the code:

```js
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
})
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

It is failing in the Main method.

Updated code using the ChainedTokenCredential:

```js
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new ChainedTokenCredential());
})
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete error message. Also, wherever possible please post the actual code and error message texts instead of screenshots.

Comment: @GauravMantri, done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Please use below code in your `Program.cs`, it works for me.

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
                {
                    var builtConfig = config.Build();
                    var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                        new Uri($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/"),
                        new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
                }
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
```

## Previous

You need to install the latest Azure CLI tools, before debugging the application by Visual Studio.

1. Set correct account in Visual Studio.

   `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Azure Service Authentication`.
2. Make sure access policy is defined for this selected account in Azure KeyVault.
3. You can replace the DefaultAzureCredential with ChainedTokenCredential, the key value secret was successfully retrieved.

   Related Blogs: [Azure Key Vault secret provider](https://security.arcus-azure.net/features/secret-store/provider/key-vault.html)

Comment: Thank you Jason. I will go install the latest CLI. I think I can confirm 1 and 2 are done. I will do step 3 and let you know.

Comment: Ok, I did all of that. Now I get an error that says System.ArgumentException: 'sources must not be empty (Parameter 'sources')'. It is talking about the parameter that needs to be passed to ChainedTokenCredential. I did notice that config has 6 sources available.

Comment: @David.Warwick Can you update your code in your post , I will check it later.

Comment: Thank you. Your updated code worked! Now to figure out what it is doing and why it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is the DefaultAzureCredential.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet   This class is grabbing your tenant id from your Visual Studio which may have multiple Azure tenant logins.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple accounts in VS or you are part of multiple tenants with your account, Visual Studio won't be able to resolve the tenant it needs to log in in order to access correctly to the KeyVault, so you need to specify it by passing a `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions` object.

For example:

```
var defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                VisualStudioTenantId = Configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAd).GetValue<string>("TenantId"),
                ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true
            });
```